# Android java+native data visibility

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Assume I have two threads in my game app (besides the main thread):

- GLRenderer thread (offered by Android's `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`)
- Another thread (game thread)

Both threads use JNI to call certain C++ (i.e. Android NDK) components of the app.

Assume I have a direct `IntBuffer` allocated in Java (e.g. from the GLRenderer thread, but don't assume this). Facts:

- this direct buffer is **read** by native code from the GLRenderer thread (i.e. by the C++ component called via JNI)
- this direct buffer is sometimes **written** from the other thread (game thread)

In the following two scenarios, what is the (best) way for synchronization (actually data visibility ensuring), i.e. to guarantee that the native code in the GLRenderer code sees an up-to-date `IntBuffer` content?

- Scenario #1: the Java code of the game thread writes to the `IntBuffer` (e.g. via `IntBuffer.put()`)
- Scenario #2: the native code called from the game thread writes to the `IntBuffer`

I was thinking that standard Java synchronization will work for both cases:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) { // the GLRenderer thread
    // ...
    synchronized (obj) {
        callNativeCode1(); // a JNI call; this is where the C++ native code reads the IntBuffer
    }

}

public void run() { // the game thread
    // ...

    synchronized (obj) {
        intBuffer.put(...); // writing the buffer from managed code
    }

    // ...
    synchronized (obj) {
        callNativeCode2(); // a JNI call; writing the buffer from C++ native code
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the "...even with empty `synchronized` blocks" was probably a nonsense, so I removed it.

Comment: If this IntBuffer points to a specified memory location that never changes during execution, then I suspect there is no synchronization needed

Comment: I can create it as a direct buffer indeed, where Android guarantees that Java won't relocate it in any way. But its content may change, and one thread writes it and another reads it. This is why I have doubts.

Comment: Basically, it would be nice if someone offered a wider insight to the topic of data visibility in Java-JNI-native interoperability.

Comment: If synchronization isn't solving the problem why not try a different approach.  Since both methods are accessed from the JAVA layer, perhaps a simple flag variable of data type AtomicBoolean could be observed by both threads before performing their operation.

Comment: Ryan, how does that guarantee up-to-date data visibility for threads? I.e. caches are written to main memory, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JNI equivalent of synchronization to guarantee native data accessed by two threads are synched:

```
//before read/writing shared data
(*env)->MonitorEnter(obj);

...                      /* synchronized block */

//after read/writing shared data
(*env)->MonitorExit(obj);
```

You can find more info in this [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section4.html).

**Edit:**
After a bit more digging, it turns out that how C code should be kept synchronized is VM-implementation dependent (see section 2.1: http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/JNI/). The scary part is this:

> ...and in most cases there is no way to know what the C code must do.

Unfortunately I can't find info on how Android specifically handles this, or whether it's handled consistently between Android versions.

However, another interesting info is provided by Android dev site (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html) which indicated that ARM CPUs provides weak memory consistency, so this may be the default behavior for C code.

Basically the issue comes down to: *Whether c data would be synchronized when thread access is synchronized in Java*. Since link 1 (http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/JNI/) doesn't give us an straight answer on this, and link 2 (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html) indicate that ARM CPUs provides weak memory consistency, doing a monitor call in C code again seem to be the safer bet.

Comment: Thanksm, sounds good. I read the relevant part of the article, too. Too bad it doesn't explain (disprove) what I said in the other comment, i.e. why Java-level synchronization does not work. That is, what is false in this: "the monitor that protects callNativeCode2() cannot be entered before callNativeCode1() returns and thus the monitor can be left."

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by this. Do you mean why is it necessary to sync in native code again if the two Java threads have been synced?

Comment: Yes, for example. In other words, what is wrong with my way of synchronization? Why do we need native-level, or the one suggested by NathanZ in his answer?

Comment: If I'm correct, it would violate the Java standard if it mattered *what* is inside the *synchronized* block (native call, Java call, whatever else).

Answer (score 2):

No knowledge of the specifics of memory sharing with JNI but I would suggest using an `AtomicIntegerArray`.

Your options are:

1. `synchronized` - You would need to somehow achieve the same in the JNI - not easy.
2. `volatile` - making a whole array `volatile` would be a problem.
3. `atomic`s - I'd say the best route.

See [Package java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) for:

> The AtomicIntegerArray, AtomicLongArray, and AtomicReferenceArray classes further extend atomic operation support to arrays of these types. These classes are also notable in **providing volatile access semantics** for their array elements, **which is not supported for ordinary arrays**.

This would essentially ensure that so long as the JNI code does not do anything to bypass the cache flush semantics of Java then the JNI package *should* see a consistent and updated view of the data.

I would recommend some significant research to confirm this but I believe this is the only way you will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that I might need to write much data (many elements) to the array. With an AtomicIntegerArray, I suppose this will have a big overhead, because each element writing is handled separately (with dedicated sync overhead, even if it is fast). It would be nice to have a mechanism where I can write a big amount of data, and then sync it (= guarantee up-to-date visibility) with the native side.

Comment: @ThomasCalc - One further alternative could be `MappedByteBuffer` - again I have no special knowledge but there may be a way of using file channels in some way so this would become feasable. That mechanism is certainly tuned for speed as you'd expect for file I/O.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, meaning you want to make sure that `callNativeCode1()` (read) and `callNativeCode2()` (write) don't occur simultanously and if both method are native, then synchronize around them will have no effect in the JNI layer.

An option would be to create a java method that is called for both read/write operations and synchronize it

```
public void synchronized readOrWrite(boolean read){
    if (read){
        callNativeCode1();
    }
    else {
        callNativeCode2();
    }
}
```

So your code would be:

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) { // the GLRenderer thread
        readOrWrite(true);
    }

    public void run() { // the game thread

    synchronized (obj) {
        intBuffer.put(...); // writing the buffer from managed code
    }

    readOrWrite(false);
```

Comment: "then synchronize around them will have no effect in the JNI layer." -- I don't understand this. The *synchronized* keyword guarantees it is a critical section, i.e. only one thread can be present in that monitor. This is regardless of the content of sync block. What am I missing?

Comment: In other words, the monitor that protects callNativeCode2() cannot be entered before callNativeCode1() returns and thus the monitor can be left.